# Paypal Beta developer site, Existing user account not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a developer account in Paypal, It was working perfectly few days back before the new beta developer site launched. I try to logged in with my credential to new website , but it show me error like:

> Please check your Email Address and PayPal Password and try again.

Even when i try to use forgot your password link it show me the error like:

> We couldn't find your email address. Please try again or select I
>   don't know what email address I used.

Both credential was correct, but i don't know why it's not working. I have searched for that and found some thread that suggested to clear your cookies and cache and try to use chrome or Firefox instead of using Internet Explorer. But no luck ,it's not working either. If someone have any suggestion for that how to solve this, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a live PayPal account to log in?

From developer.paypal.com:

> Please log in with a **PayPal account**. After you log in, you can import
>   your Sandbox test accounts using the email address and password you
>   used previously with the Sandbox.

Comment: No i don't use live paypal account, I am using the account detail which was created from sandbox.paypal.com . But it was not working on new site, what can i do, it's not even taken my email address to reset my password.

Comment: That's intended; you have to use a live PayPal account for logging in to the developer site. If you don't have one yet, you can create a Premier account to use. It doesn't need any financial data (card/bank) attached to it. You'll merely use that to login to developer.paypal.com going forward. Once logged in, you'll be able to import your existing Sandbox test accounts.

Comment: So i have to signup to live paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

The is a bug with the "import feature", the form validation of email format fails if emails cannot contain a ".". As my original sandbox email contained a "." i cannot import.

Comment: I agree that this bug exists -- PLEASE FIX IT, @PayPal_Robert -- but I don't think the OP was encountering this problem.

Comment: Yes, rest assured this will be fixed as soon as possible. Shouldn't have happened -- apologies.